# how to switch application winappdriver in java

Tags: java, winappdriver

I want to switch File Explorer and Chrome browser.

how to switch application?

in my code

```
   @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        try {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe");
            ExplorerSession = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities);
            ExplorerSession.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            actions = new Actions(ExplorerSession);
            modules = new Modules(ExplorerSession);}
```

can I generate new Session?

I reference next link

https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/tree/v1.0#creating-a-desktop-session
https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/35a659232060a6e436cbb8393ae9a09bab12bc89/Samples/C%23/StickyNotesTest/StickyNotesSession.cs

but I could't resolve this problem

Not enough information in Java.

No API documents found, either.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need different objects of ChromeDriver and WindowsDriver. The ChromeDriver object will operate using Selenium, the WindowsDriver object will use the WinAppDriver. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem by using the info in the first link in the OP to get the NativeWindowHandle and use that to bring focus to each application. I had to append 0x to the front of the Handle returned by my application in order to pass it to the desired capabilities in the next test, but otherwise the instructions in the link worked well for me.

```
    String NativeWindowHandle = driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("ShellForm").getAttribute("NativeWindowHandle");
    int natWinHandleInt = Integer.parseInt(NativeWindowHandle);
    String natWinHandleStr = Integer.toHexString(natWinHandleInt);
    natWinHandle = "0x"+natWinHandleStr;

    DesiredCapabilities appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    appCapabilities.setCapability("appTopLevelWindow", natWinHandle);
    driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), appCapabilities);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for providing an answer. But it is recommended for good answer to include both explanation and code examples. Would be great if you could help with small code snippet to illustrate the approach.